# How to create two roles in a MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roles

I'm new to MVC and I am creating a MVC project. My goal is to just display a website that only I can edit/post/delete and others can acess and only view the page.

I have seen some solutions including:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User, Administrator")]
```

I already have a DB and I used Entity Framework code first.

How to approach the problem from here? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-membership-provider/

Comment: https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-membership-provider-to-create-users-roles-mapping-roles-to-users

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-aspnet-membership-provider

Comment: http://logcorner.com/how-to-configure-custom-membership-and-role-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24182340/7538024

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Identity Framework?
If not, create a empty project, then install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples this package will create an ASP.NET MVC application that support for authentication and authorization. You can research base on this project, hope this help for you.